# How to combine strings inside foreach into single string PHP

Tags: php, string, foreach

I have code like this

```
$word = 'foo';
$char_buff = str_split($word);

foreach ($char_buff as $chars){
    echo var_dump($chars);
}
```

The output was

```
string(1) "f" 
string(1) "o" 
string(1) "o"
```

For some reasons, I want to make the output become only 1 string like this:

```
string(3) "foo"
```

I tried with this

```
$char.=$chars;
echo var_dump($char);
```

But it shows error `Undefined variable: char`.

Comment: If you want it all together, why are you splitting it?

Comment: Define $char as an empty string before your loop

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have a good reason for splitting it up, only to put it back together again:

```
$word = 'foo';
$result = "";
$char_buff = str_split($word);

foreach ($char_buff as $char){
    $result .= $char;
}

echo var_dump($result);
```

Which outputs the following:

```
string(3) "foo"
```

Comment: All of you guys have a great answer but I choose Jonathan Sampson as the best answer. My purpose with this is I want to create a key based on the user inputted character. So first I convert each string characters to a variable, like $f, $o, and $o. Then each those variables have a unique string. And then I combine those unique strings, and store in my database. So basically the output will not "foo" again. That's why I need it.

Answer (score 2):

[`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) converts a string to an array. There's no need to use this function if you want to keep the whole word.

Comment: My purpose with this is I want to create a key based on the user inputted character. So first I convert each string characters to a variable, like $f, $o, and $o. Then each those variables have a unique string. And then I combine those unique strings, and store in my database. So basically the output will not "foo" again. That's why I need it. I just want to know the basic method to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use implode, much like this:
`$string = implode('', $char_buff);`

Comment: Empty glue is the default setting, you can omit the empty string parameter in this case.

Comment: @mickmackusa Back in 2012 when I wrote the answer, that was not the case...

Comment: There is nothing in the changlelog to suggest that that is true.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php  Please site proof of your claim.

Answer (score 1):

So, why do you split it just to make it a string again?

```
$word='foo'
$char_buff = str_split($word);

$final = array();
foreach ($char_buff as $chars){
    $final[] = $chars;
}

var_dump( implode('', $final) );
```

Comment: Empty glue is the default setting, you can omit the empty string parameter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for implode()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

As for the code you posted
$chars .= $char;
is probably what you were trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Kind of strange to split a string, and then glue it together again, but here goes:

```
$word='foo'
$char_buff = str_split($word);

// this is what is missing, you have to define a variable first
$newword = "";

foreach ($char_buff as $chars){
     $newword .= $chars;
}

echo var_dump($newword);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$word = 'foo';
$char_buff = str_split($word);

// here is the trick
$length = count($char_buff);
$char_buff[$length] = $word;

foreach ($char_buff as $chars)
{
    echo var_dump($chars);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of you are looking for this answer.
I think var_dump() is no longer necessary for this problem.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['test'])){
        $result = '';
        for($x=1;$x<=4;$x++){
            $ans = $_POST['ans'.$x];
            $result .= $ans;
        } 
    echo $result; 
    }
?>
```

Here is the HTML

```html
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $url;?>">
 <input type="checkbox" name="ans1" value="A">A 
 <input type="checkbox" name="ans2" value="B">B 
 <input type="checkbox" name="ans3" value="C">C 
 <input type="checkbox" name="ans4" value="D">D 
 <input type="submit" name="test" value="Submit Answer">
</form>
```