# PHP: Concat a string in a foreach loop

Tags: php, concatenation

How can I concat a string inside a for each loop? What I'm doing below works ok without the loop, but is there a way I can put the loop in there without ending the `$body[{{body}}]` and starting it again?

```
$carrier = array (
    'SAS' => array('alias' => 'sas', 'name' => 'SAS'),
    'British Airways' => array('alias' => 'british_airways', 'name' => 'British Airways')
);

$body['{{body}}'] = '';

$body['{{body}}'] .= 'Line one'.

    foreach ($carrier as $key=>$value) {
        '<option value='.$value['alias'].'>'.$value['name'].'</option>'.;
    }

'Line two'.
'Line three'.
'Line four';

print_r($body);
```

Comment: FYI, you want to concatenate the string inside the foreach loop.  You wouldn't say that you want to concatenate a loop.

Comment: Where is your `select` tag? That's invalid markup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this - you have to concatenate each line generated in the foreach loop.

```
$carrier = array (
    'SAS' => array('alias' => 'sas', 'name' => 'SAS'),
    'British Airways' => array('alias' => 'british_airways', 'name' => 'British Airways')
);

$body['{{body}}'] = 'Line one';

foreach ($carrier as $key=>$value) {
    $body['{{body}}'] .= '<option value=' . $value['alias'] . '>' . $value['name'] . '</option>';
}

$body['{{body}}'] .= 'Line two';
$body['{{body}}'] .= 'Line three';
$body['{{body}}'] .= 'Line four';

print_r($body);
```

Comment: Still the same. There are line after the foreach too. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in C:\web\apache\htdocs\esp\test\concat.php on line 12`

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left a dot in there.  I'll update with the complete code.  Sometimes brevity is not helpful  :)

Comment: Now I've posted the complete code.  Notice that I simplified the initialization of `$body['{{body}}']`.  Each line that starts with `$body['{{body}}'] .=` ends with a semicolon.  I've not tested it (no php environment, sorry), but I would expect it to work.

Answer (score 3):

```
$word = 'foo';
$result = "";
$char_buff = str_split($word);

foreach ($char_buff as $char){
  $result .= $char;
}

echo var_dump($result);
```

Which outputs the following:

```
string(3) "foo"
```

[How to combine strings inside foreach into single string PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862083/how-to-combine-strings-inside-foreach-into-single-string-php)