# how to combine strings to a single string in a foreach? php

Tags: php, string, foreach

i have this foreach code:

```
if(property_exists($product, "images")){

    foreach($product->images as $images){


        $PIC_url = $images->original_url;



            $whole_pic_url = "https://www.path.to".$PIC_url . ',';

            echo "<pre>";
                var_dump ($whole_pic_url);
            echo "</pre>";
    }
} else {

    $whole_pic_url = 'https://path.to/alternative/picture.jpg';

}
```

the output is:

```
string(54) "https://path.to/the/picture_1.jpg,"
string(68) "https://path.to/the/picture_2.jpg,"
string(69) "https://path.to/the/picture_3.jpg,"
string(69) "https://path.to/the/picture_4.jpg,"
string(73) "https://path.to/the/picture_5.jpg,"
```

For the CSV all paths must be a row separated by commas like this:

```
https://path.to/the/picture_1.jpg,https://path.to/the/picture_2.jpg,ect.
```

this is the output of the array for my CSV:

```
`Array([0] => 1;Article_Name;path/to/the/article;category;price;ID;5;description;available ;https://path.to/the/picture_5.jpg,;2
```

)`

Only the last value is written to the array ***https://path.to/the/picture_5.jpg,***

i have tried with this examples: [How to combine strings inside foreach into single string PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862083/how-to-combine-strings-inside-foreach-into-single-string-php)

but without success, i hope somebody can help me

thank you in advance for your help

best regards
dashmir

Comment: Don't use var_dump. Use echo and build the string you need

Comment: Hello Andreas, inside my if (foreach), i can see with echo the paths in a row,that is what i want but outside the  if (foreach) its still written the last value in the CSV Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want all images to be concatenated with a "," separator, you can just keep concatenating to `$whole_pic_url` using `.=`

Just declare the variable and initiate with an empty string.
`$whole_pic_url = ""`

Then in your loop do:
`$whole_pic_url .= "https://www.path.to".$PIC_url . ',';`

The entire code should look like:

```
$whole_pic_url = "";
if(property_exists($product, "images")){

    foreach($product->images as $images){


        $PIC_url = $images->original_url;



            $whole_pic_url .= "https://www.path.to".$PIC_url . ',';

            echo "<pre>";
                var_dump ($whole_pic_url);
            echo "</pre>";
    }
} 
else {
    $whole_pic_url .= 'https://path.to/alternative/picture.jpg';

}
```

You can all group all the images into an array, then implode the array to be a string.

```
$images_array = [];
if(property_exists($product, "images")){

    foreach($product->images as $images){


        $PIC_url = $images->original_url;
            $images_array[] = "https://www.path.to".$PIC_url . ',';

            echo "<pre>";
                var_dump ($whole_pic_url);
            echo "</pre>";
    }
} 
else {
    $images_array[] = 'https://path.to/alternative/picture.jpg';

}
$whole_pic_url = implode(",", $images_array);
```

Comment: Hi thank you Amin. That was the solutions, best regards from switzerland :-)

Comment: all good bro, thumb me up lol, mark as best answer ^_^

Comment: how can i mark it as best answer? its my 2 post here :)

Comment: all good, you've made it :)